# Code first still trying to create database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I get always this exception, even if Database initializer is set to CreateIfNotExists.

```
Additional information: Cannot create file 'C:\\Users\\Krab\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Customer_UI\\customers2.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.

CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

Why is EF trying to create the database even if it already exists?

**App.config**

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Customer.CustomersContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\Krab\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Customer_UI\\customers2.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**DbContext:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Customer
{
    public class CustomersContext : DbContext
    {
        public CustomersContext() : base("Customer.CustomersContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<CustomersContext>());
            //Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            //System.Console.WriteLine(Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
        }

        public DbSet<CustomerDb> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Open up the hood and take a look inside.  I apologize in advance for the convention over configuration humor.

Comment: Can you give more code context for Database initialization? No pun intended.

Comment: Mkae sure it isn't open (in VS for example).

Comment: @HenkHolterman: yeah i noticed now i cannot delete that mdf file, because it tells file is in use.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: can it be in use because the program ends with exception and the DbContext wasnt properly closed?

Comment: Several possibilities but a terminated app won't keep it open. The Server Explore Window could.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the escaped file path has something to do with this.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: i couldnt delete it even if i closed VS. It tells file is used in SQL server.

Comment: That doesn't look like a `(LocalDB)\v11.0` db then. Did you have a different ConnString earlier?  Pick a new name and try again. Or maybe jsut kill IIS-express.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: i tried what you said and now it looks ok. Thanks for help.

Comment: You can write down exaclty what you did (which one) as a self-answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to escape backslashes in App.config files.

My guess is that whatever mechanism that checks for an existing database does *not* correctly resolve file paths with double directory separators (`C:\\Users\\...)`.

EF would then go ahead and try to create a new database, but whatever mechanism that creates new databases *does* correctly resolve file paths with double directory separators. Resulting in an `IOException` because the file exists.

If my hunch is correct, simply unescaping the path would have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok now it looks fine.

1. Changed name of connection string to another one
2. Removed that escaping from .mdf filename in connection string
3. Changed .mdf filename to another one, so i am not using the old one

Answer (score 0):

The error is referring to a file on the SQL Server instance, wherever that is. In my case, it was a different machine. I had renamed the database in hopes of getting EF to recreate it